# returns error 'UNSUPPORTED'' while run app

Tags: android-studio, run-app

I just updated my Android Studio to version 3.5. When I run App using my phone, it successfully compiles, but an error occurs during the installation process.

this is the error message:

> Installation did not succeed.
>   The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 1472245' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED''

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 24):

You can solve this problem by disabling MIUI optimization from developed options:

Settings -> Developer options -> MIUI optimization

Disable it and it will ask to reboot the device, after that the app can be installed

Comment: It works for all MI devices which have MIUI optimization.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Finally after some research I got it working. Disabled developer mode on the phone. Then enabled it again and enabled all options like USB install, USB debugging etc, disabled MIUI optimization and rebooted the phone. After reboot, the app installed and is working fine.

Comment: mark it as the right answer so that it benefits other people as well

Comment: It's impossible to accept it because I'm not the one who asked the question!. I can only upvote it which I did